# When to use OpenWeb() vs RootWeb

Tags: development, object-model, dispose

I am a little confused on the pro's and con's of each. When is it good to use OpenWeb() vs RootWeb, especially in the context of a using statement.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You would never use `RootWeb` in the context of a `using` statement and `OpenWeb()` isn't useful unless the URL specified in the `SPSite` constructor was a sub web of the site collection in lieu of just the site collection URL.

So, you should never do this:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{
    // do something with web
}
```

...and `OpenWeb()` is useful in a scenario like this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev/subsite"))
{
    // RootWeb would return the http://sharepointdev and OpenWeb() would return "subsite"
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    { 
        // do something with web
    }
}
```

...but `OpenWeb()` doesn't do anything in this scenario, except create an extra `SPWeb` object...use `RootWeb`:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev"))
{
   // do something with site.RootWeb
}
```

Comment: What is you are creating a workflow and you don't know if it will be the main site or a subsite. Would it be wise to always go with example two in that case?

Comment: You could, but I would probably check to see if the Url I used to create the SPSite object equals SPSite.RootWeb.Url first...if it doesn't then go with OpenWeb()...it it does then use RootWeb.

Comment: You can find more information on the topic why you should not use SPSite.RootWeb in a using statement here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/10/04/updated-spsite-rootweb-dispose-guidance.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get hold of a subsite using GUID or URL (server-relative or site-relative), *OpenWeb(*) should be used.The *SPWeb* returned from *OpenWeb()* should be manually disposed.
Also, want to share [this](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2009/03/why-i-dont-use-openweb/) for something interesing on *OpenWeb()* .

*RootWeb* gives you the top most *SPWeb* associated with *SPSite*.
Although, you can also get it using *OpenWeb()*, *RootWeb* is preferred as it does not require explicit disposal of SPWeb object it provides.